# how to access a custom viewcollection cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a ViewCollection named photoCollection. Each cel is a custom cell which has UIImageView.

How do I access the 1st, 2nd item of photoCollection?

```
let cell = photoCollection.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: 1, section: 1)) as! photoCollectionViewCell
```

return nil

I don't know why.
Thanks.

Comment: is the cell visible when you call this function?

Comment: It returns nil if the cell is not visible. If you want to retrieve it's image, text or something like that, don't do it that way, ask the datasource (potentially the array that populate your cells).

Comment: Like @Larme said, the CollectionView is a UI element for presenting collection of data. Meaning you have data, and you have UI. So whatever your data is, if it is an array, you use that for any logic you need. the cell is meant to be stupid, you should just trigger its delegate functions to achieve UI goals mostly.

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, the function `cellForItem(at:)` will return `nil` if the cell is not visible at the time.

If you have a specific cell that needs access any random time, then you could try something like below:

```
lazy var yourSpecificCell: PhotoCollectionViewCell = {
    let cell = self.collectionView!.dequeueReusableCell(withRuseIdentifier: "SOMETHING", for: IndexPath(item: 1, section: 1)) as! photoCollectionViewCell
    return cell
}()
```

and in your `UICollectionViewDataSource`,

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.item == 1 { return self.yourSpecificCell }
    // else, return something else...
}
```